# Extension method on string[] to lowercase all elements?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, static-methods

Consider the following method example:

```
public static string[] ParseOptions()
{
    return Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
}
```

**What would I have to do to create an extension that would make ParseOptions() return all command line arguments in lower case?**

I would like to be able to use the extension as follows:

```
var argArray = ParseOptions().MyExtToLower();
```

*Note: I'm asking this to better understand how to create an extension for a method. I'm not actually interested in getting lower case command line arguments this way.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static string[] MyExtToLower(this string[] source)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        source[i] = source[i].ToLower();
    }
    return source;    
}
```

Notice the `this` keyword in the parameter list.  That is what makes it possible to call the method like this:

```
var argArray = ParseOptions().MyExtToLower();
```

To be clear, you're not actually adding an extension to a method here.  What you are doing is adding an extension to the type that the method returns.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be talking about Fluent Interfaces. Look at this example - http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2010/06/26/how-to-write-fluent-interface-with-c-and-lambda.aspx

Or, you can create extension methods on the type you are returning ( in your case, `string[]` ) to get the method chaining - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For the syntax you describe you would have to extend String[] or possibly IEnumerable<String> the following way:

```
public static class MyExtensions {

  public static String[] MyExtToLower(this String[] strings) {

    return strings.Select(s => s.toLower()).ToArray();

  }

  public static IEnumerable<String> MyExtToLower(this IEnumerable<String> strings) {

    return strings.Select(s => s.toLower());

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't create extension of methods, you create methods which extend objects' capabilities. Those methods must be static and part of a static class. They must have one parameter marked with the `this` keyword to indicate which object you want to extend. In your case, you must write something like:

```
// the class must be static, I usually declare a class reserved for extension method.
// I mark it as partial so that I can put every method in the same file where I use it.
public static partial class Extension {
    // This is the extension method; it must be static. Note the 'this' keyword before
    // the first parameter: it tells the compiler extends the string[] type.
    public static MyExtToLower( this string[ ] args ) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Note that you cannot override instance method. Altough you can have a method with the same signature as an instance method that method will be never called due to the way the compiler binds to.